# Hyperlinks in ArcGIS Pro not working

Tags: arcgis-pro, hyperlink

I am in the process of moving years of ArcMap projects to ArcGIS Pro 3.1.2 and have run into a serious issue. I have thousands of hyperlinks in the data tables which are in dbf format (derived from a master Excel file) or shapefiles.

The hyperlinks are in the form of \AmlampGIS\Wisconsin-ScottRegion\AMU-AmundsenGlacier\Petro\AMU17290.pdf, relative to the root of the drive. My file structure scheme is to have all (or most) the required data, raster, etc. files under a single folder specific to a given area. This has worked well in ArcMap.

As a test, I have started a new project in Pro, again selecting to place the gdb and tbx in this folder along with the project file. I bring in the data file (or import the existing mxd) without any problem.

When I open the attribute table the hyperlink appears to be good, but nothing happens when I click on it. When I CTRL-Click up pops the following message:

[image]

Notice the redundant sections of the paths. Also, I didn’t ask Pro to use the C:\Users\ folder for the working directory.

How to make Pro do what I want?

What is missing from my workflow?

Here is the entire attribute table.
[image]

And here is the point popup window again showing bogus paths.
[image]

---

I started going down the road that @GBG was describing about the working directory. Did that, but that did not seem to help the hyperlink path issue. I have been spending a bunch of time looking at videos and sites about configuring popups and hyperlinks and so far have not found anything remotely dealing with the issues with the duplicating path sections that come into the attribute table.

Could it be that path structure as seen in the attribute table needs to be changed?

I also notice that all the back slashes originally used in the path have been changed to forward slashes.
Also spent a bunch of time fiddling with configuring pop ups, but had not luck making anything work hyperlink-wise. I did configure the popup to display the link to the photo but again there is the file:/// that got appended to the front of the path (see bottom of image).

[image]

Comment: Don't worry about the working directory.  Every project has one, and that looks like the default working directory for a project which has not yet been saved anywhere.

Comment: What is the exact contents of the attribute value that you CTRL-clicked on?  Double-click on it in the attributes table, and copy the entire thing then edit your question and paste that entire value into your question post here, all on its own line without any other text.

Comment: You need to reconfigure how popup work in Pro.  https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/mapping/navigation/use-hyperlinks-in-pop-ups.htm

Answer (score 0):

To fix the working directory you can access that in properties/options.  Use caution because any new project will default to user drives and will need to be reset.  As a result I built a basic starter project with correct project paths (to a local drive and not a network profile location) and work from there.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think that there should only be two slashes after **file:** and before D:. Mine wouldn't work until I corrected that. I also had to change the drive letter to the name of the drive.

The ESRI help file shows 3 slashes but I think that is a typo.